# What is syntax error of this [@[bar foo]] formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image]

=IF([@[Amani''s Taxable Income (by bracket)]]=0,0,IF(([@[Amani''s Taxable Income (by bracket)]]+[@[If taxable income is over:]]+1)>=[@[but not over:]],D8,[@[Tax rate]]))

The system said there was a syntax error in this formula.

Can anyone help me to figure it out?

Comment: Your formula references the `Tax rate` column which doesn't  exist in the table.